# Visual Studio extension to draw a rule between class members

Tags: visual-studio-2010, plugins, resharper

Is there a Visual Studio 2010 extension that draws a dividing rule between the members of a class? VisualBasic had this feature:

[image]

I'm considering writing such extension if it doesn't exist yet -- probably a Resharper plugin if it allows this kind of interaction with the IDE. Any directions? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [All Margins](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/465a0d53-5133-4edd-a0cd-94484fe3d853/) Extension, it doesn't do exactly what you want but will make your code blocks clearer by putting coloured vertical lines between them. Not sure how it looks with VB but it works well with C#.

Resharper gives you the File Structure window (CTRL+ALT+F) that helps you navigate between blocks of your code so you may not need the extra clutter in your code window.